# Hexadecimal numbers vs. hexadecimal enocding (with base64 as well)

Tags: cryptography, hex

Encoding with hexadecimal numbers seems to be different from using hexadecimals to represent numbers. For example, then hex number 0x40 to me should be equal to 64, or `BA_{64}`, but when I put it through [this](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php) hex to base64 converter, I get the output: `QA==` which to me is equal to some number times 64. Why is this?

Also when I check the integer value of the hex string `deadbeef` I get 3735928559, but when I check it other places I get: 222 173 190 239. Why is this?

Addendum: So I guess it is because it is easier to break the number into bit chunks than treat it as a whole number when encoding? That is pretty confusing to me but I guess I get it.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to read this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

In summary, base64 specifies a specific encoding, which involves using different values for letters than their ASCII encoding.

For the second part, one source is treating the entire string as a 32 bit integer, and the other is dividing it into bytes and giving the value of each byte.

Comment: I've read the wikipedia article several times, and continue to read it, but must have not absorbed what you think is there. So base64 does *not* treat the number as a 32 bit integer, rather breaking it into chunks?

Comment: ah I actually see it now: "Groups of 6 bits (6 bits have a maximum of 26 = 64 different binary values) are converted into individual numbers from left to right (in this case, there are four numbers in a 24-bit string), which are then converted into their corresponding Base64 character values."

Comment: @user2407894 If this question is now answered, please either accept an existing answer or post an answer yourself and accept it when the time limit expires.